# Finding $2\sin x + 4\sin y$, given $\sin^2x+\cos^2y = \frac{11}{16}$ and $\sin\frac12(x+y) \cos\frac12(x-y) = \frac{5}{8}$

Tags: trigonometry

I think my basics are pretty weak, I am not able to solve this question.

> $$\begin{align}
> \sin^2x+\cos^2y &= \frac{11}{16} \tag1 \\[4pt]
> \sin\frac12(x+y) \cos\frac12(x-y) &= \frac{5}{8} \tag2\\
> \\
> \end{align}$$
> Find the value of
> $$2\sin x + 4\sin y$$
> (The answer is stated to be $4$.)

Sorry for the horrible $\LaTeX$.

***MY APPROACH:***

I did not focus on simplifying the first equation, so I simplified the second equation by using the formula $2\sin(x)\cos(y) = \sin(x + y) + \sin(x - y)$.

**From 2**

\begin{align*}
\sin\left(\frac{x + y}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{x - y}{2}\right) & = \frac{5}{8}\\
2\sin\left(\frac{x + y}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{x - y}{2}\right) & = \frac{5}{4}\\
\sin x + \sin y = \frac{5}{4}
\end{align*}

**Squaring this we get equation 3,**

$$\sin^2x + \sin^2y + 2\sin x\sin y = \frac{25}{16}$$

**Now I am adding equations 1 and 3 together**

\begin{align*}
\sin^2x + \sin^2y + 2\sin x \sin y + \sin^2x + \cos^2y & = \frac{25}{16} + \frac{11}{16}\\
\sin^2x + \sin^2y + 2\sin x \sin y + \sin^2x + \cos^2y & = \frac{36}{16}\\
\sin^2x + (\sin^2y + \cos^2y) + 2\sin x \sin y + \sin^2x & = \frac{9}{4}\\
2\sin^2x + 2\sin x \sin y & = \frac{9}{4}
\end{align*}

**Taking $2\sin x$ as common**

$$2\sin x(\sin x + \sin y) = \frac{9}{4}$$

**But we know the value of $\boldsymbol{\sin x + \sin y}$ from equation number 2. Therefore,**

\begin{align*}
2\sin x(\sin x + \sin y) & = \frac{9}{4}\\
2\sin x \cdot \frac{5}{4} & = \frac{9}{4}\\
\sin x & = \frac{9}{10} 
\end{align*}

Then I put this value in equation 2 and got the value of $\sin y$ as $7/10$.

But when I used these values to find the solution for $2\sin x + 4\sin y$, I got a wrong answer $16/5$.

Comment: Formatting tip:  Typing `$\sin x$` and `$\cos x$` produces $\sin x$ and $\cos x$, respectively.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Sir can you help me solve this problem ?

Comment: @NotRamanujan, please, read my answer and upvote it if you like.

Comment: While I was editing your post, I noticed that you wrote $\sin^2x + (\sin^2y + \cos^2y) + 2\sin x\sin y + \sin^2x = \frac{9}{4}$, then wrote $2\sin^2x + 2\sin x\sin y = \frac{9}{4}$.  This does not make sense since $\sin^2y + \cos^2y = 1$.  You should have obtained $2\sin^2x + 2\sin x\sin y = \frac{5}{4}$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig but $sin^2x + cos^2y$ = 11 / 16, am i not supposed to consider that value ? Is there any rule I am missing ? oh god.

Comment: Read what I said again:  You had the term $\sin^2y + \cos^2y$ in the penultimate line of your section "Now I am adding equations 1 and 3 together".  Since $\sin^2y + \cos^2y = 1$, you should have subtracted $1$ from $9/4$ to obtain $2\sin^2x + 2\sin x \sin y = 5/4$ in the last line of that section.

Comment: @NotRamanujan, since $\;\sin^2y+\cos^2y=1\,,\,$ you get $$2\sin^2x + 1+2\sin x \sin y= \frac94$$ which is equivalent to $$2\sin^2x + 2\sin x \sin y= \frac54$$

Comment: @N.F.Taussig  Thank you for spending your time on such a dumb mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you calculated, $\sin(x) + \sin(y) = 5/4$. therefore, $2\sin(x) + 2\sin(y) = 2.5$ . The question has required you to calculate $ 2\sin(x) + 4\sin(y)$ which is 2.5 + 2 sin(y). In order to calculate sin(y), put $\sin(x) = 5/4 - \sin(y)$ and use the other equation $ \sin^2x + \cos^2y = 11/16$ and put $\cos^2y = 1 - \sin^2y$ to solve the exercise. I calculated it and got 4.

Answer (score 3):

As you write in your post, $\;\color{brown
}{\sin x+\sin y=\dfrac54}\,.$

Consequently, $\;\color{brown}{\sin x=\dfrac54-\sin y}\;.$

Moreover, from $\;\color{brown}{\sin^2x+\cos^2y=\dfrac{11}{16}}\;,\;$ it follows that

$\left(\dfrac54-\sin y\right)^2+1-\sin^2y=\dfrac{11}{16}\;,$

$\dfrac{25}{16}+\sin^2y-\dfrac52\sin y+1-\sin^2y=\dfrac{11}{16}\;,$

$\sin y=\dfrac34\,.$

Consequently,

$\begin{align}2\sin x+4\sin y&=2\left(\sin x+\sin y\right)+2\sin y=\\[3pt]&=2\cdot\dfrac54+2\cdot\dfrac34=4\,.\end{align}$

Comment: can you tell me what was wrong with my approach? it would be a great help. Your solution matches the solution in my question bank.

Comment: @NotRamanujan, look at N.F.Taussig’s comment and you will know what is wrong in your approach. Actually $\,\sin x=\frac12\,,\,$ hence $\,\sin y=\frac34\,.$